# asyncio.create_subprocess_exec console window opening for each call

Tags: windows, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio, windows-console

I have a function which asynchronously runs a subprocess command and returns the results. It looks like this:

```
import asyncio
async def async_subprocess_command(*args):
    # Create subprocess
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *args,
        # stdout and stderr must a pipe to be accessible as process.stdout
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    # Wait for the subprocess to finish
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()

    #Remove final carriage return from string
    stdout_formatted = stdout.decode().strip().replace('\r', '')
    stderr_formatted = stderr.decode().strip().replace('\r', '')
    # Return stdout and sterr
    return stdout_formatted, stderr_formatted
```

If I can afford to work synchronously, I tend to use this call to the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.getoutput([parameter1,parameter2,parameter3])
```

When I call the `subprocess.getoutput` synchronously (assuming I'm calling an external tool), no console window opens. When I call `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` asynchronously (again, assuming I'm calling an external tool), a console window pops up for a brief moment for each call to it and makes the computer difficult to interact with until the asynchronous calls are complete.

Is there a way I can asynchronously call `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` without the console window popping up?

Comment: Use a process [creation flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863). You can prevent allocating a console at all via `creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS`. Or instead, allocate a console that doesn't create a window via `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW`. The option to not create a window may seem pointless, but it improves compatibility with some console applications since the process is still attached to a console, plus this windowless console will be inherited by child processes. In contrast, when using a detached process, child processes will allocate a new console.

Comment: Thanks for this info - I was able to adjust the original function with this and even make it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eryksun's suggestion, I was able to use the original function with an extra parameter (creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS). It is slightly faster than using the asyncio.create_subprocess_shell function in the first answer and works as expected. See eryksun's comment above for more info on other benefits.

```
async def async_subprocess_command(*args):

    #CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000 using detatched_process is slightly faster
    DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
    # Create subprocess
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *args,
        # stdout and stderr must a pipe to be accessible as process.stdout
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS,
        )
    # Wait for the subprocess to finish
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()

    #Remove final carriage return from string
    stdout_formatted = stdout.decode().strip().replace('\r', '')
    stderr_formatted = stderr.decode().strip().replace('\r', '')

    # Return stdout and sterr
    return stdout_formatted, stderr_formatted
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in another function:

```
async def async_subprocess_command(cmd):
        '''
        cmd should be a string exactly as you 
        write into the cmd line
        '''
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd, 
                stdin=None, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
                stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

        stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()

        stdout_formatted = stdout.decode().strip().replace('\r', '')
        stderr_formatted = stderr.decode().strip().replace('\r', '')

        return stdout_formatted, stderr_formatted
```

Comment: Using the shell is not a good solution for running an arbitrary `cmd`, especially if any substrings come from user input.

Comment: In my use case, there is no user input - the cmd is written by the application based on what function has been called and what parameters are applicable to that function call.